Make element fit the container without scaling up
I have a problem to solve that sounds simple. Let's say I got a layout of a header, content and footer. Then I have a row of items in the content, filling all the space. Each item in the content section is equal in width and each has one child.
The children need to feel their parents perfectly, taking as much space as they can, but never scaling up. In other words, something that object-fit: scale-down would do if these were images.
Let's say the sizes of the elements I need to fit in there are:

200 x 300
1920 x 1080
1080 x 1920

This is the result I'm looking for:

I'm struggling to make it work correctly, bigger elements always either overflowing the container or getting clipped.


html,
body {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  background-color: #444;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 50px;
}

.middle {
  background-color: #222;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #666;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block {
  background-color: #f80;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, orange, purple);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.block1 {
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.block2 {
  max-height: 1080px;
  max-width: 1920px;
}

.block3 {
  max-height: 1920px;
  max-width: 1080px;
}
<div class="layout">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="items">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="block block1"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="block block2"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="block block3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>



So to sum up, I got rectangles of certain size that can be scaled down, not up, and obviously can't change the aspect ratio. By the way, I tried to experiment with aspect-ratio too, without success.
Can it be done without JavaScript calculations?

@CBroe yes, I do know the dimensions, which I suppose could help :)

It does seem to be achievable with aspect-ratio property and @container queries:

Remove height: 100%; width: 100%; from .block to allow auto width and height.

For "horizontal" blocks (width > height):


Remove max-height, keep max-width, add width: 100%.
Add aspect-ratio containing width / height values without pixels (aspect-ratio: 300 / 200; for .block1);
Add @container query to flip the sizing when there is not enough space. For .block1:

@container (aspect-ratio > 300 / 200) and (height < 200px) {
  .block1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
  }
}


For "vertical" blocks (height > width):


Remove max-width, keep max-height, add height: 100%.
Add aspect-ratio similarly as to "horizontal" - width / height (aspect-ratio: 1080 / 1920; for .block3);
Add @container query to flip the sizing when there is not enough space. For .block3:

@container (aspect-ratio < 1080 / 1920) and (width < 1080px) {
  .block3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}


Add container-type: size; to .item so it's declared as a size query container.

Snippet:


html,
body {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  background-color: #444;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 50px;
}

.middle {
  background-color: #222;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #666;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  container-type: size;
}

.block {
  background-color: #f80;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, orange, purple);
}

.block1 {
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 300 / 200;
}

@container (aspect-ratio > 300 / 200) and (height < 200px) {
  .block1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
  }
}

.block2 {
  max-width: 1920px;
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1920 / 1080;
}

@container (aspect-ratio > 1920 / 1080) and (height < 1080px) {
  .block2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
  }
}

.block3 {
  max-height: 1920px;
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1080 / 1920;
}

@container (aspect-ratio < 1080 / 1920) and (width < 1080px) {
  .block3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
<div class="layout">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="items">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="block block1"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="block block2"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="block block3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>



Update
This is an extension of author`s (@Robo Robok) simplified solution with CSS variables.
Properties are declared once in a common .block class:
.block {
  --bw: var(--w);
  --bh: none;
  
  width: auto;
  width: calc(var(--bw) * 1px);
  
  height: calc(var(--bh) * 1px);
  max-height: calc(var(--bh)/var(--bh) * 100%);
  
  aspect-ratio: var(--w) / var(--h);
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, orange, purple);
}

Variables are set for each block individually, for example:
.block1 {
  --w: 300;
  --h: 200;
}
@container (aspect-ratio > 300 / 200) {
  .block1 {
    --bw: none;
    --bh: var(--h);
  }
}

Grouping @containers or using variables and style() queries would minimize the code, however currently:

Container queries cannot be grouped :


It's not possible to target multiple containers in a single container query.


The aspect-ratio feature does not support CSS variables.
Experimental style() queries are only partially supported in some browsers.

Snippet:


html,
body {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  background-color: #444;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 50px;
}

.middle {
  background-color: #222;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #666;
  container-type: size;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}

.block {
  --bw: var(--w);
  --bh: none;
  width: auto;
  width: calc(var(--bw) * 1px);
  height: calc(var(--bh) * 1px);
  max-height: calc(var(--bh)/var(--bh) * 100%);
  aspect-ratio: var(--w) / var(--h);
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, orange, purple);
}

.block1 {
  --w: 300;
  --h: 200;
}

@container (aspect-ratio > 300 / 200) {
  .block1 {
    --bw: none;
    --bh: var(--h);
  }
}

.block2 {
  --w: 1920;
  --h: 1080;
}

@container (aspect-ratio > 1920 / 1080) {
  .block2 {
    --bw: none;
    --bh: var(--h);
  }
}

.block3 {
  --w: 1080;
  --h: 1920;
}

@container (aspect-ratio > 1080 / 1920) {
  .block3 {
    --bw: none;
    --bh: var(--h);
  }
}
<div class="layout">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="items">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="block block1"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="block block2"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="block block3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>




Perhaps using container queries to separate rules for horizontal and vertical .item elements would work?

Appreciate your feedback! I didn't notice that issue. The answer has been improved to handle those cases. Surely, it uses container queries.

It works great now. I wonder if it could be simplified somehow, I have a whole bunch of dynamically-sized elements and adding all those media queries dynamically feel a bit hacky.

@hedfol please take a look at my answer here, I simplified your solution.

Thanks, I've added a "variable" version of your solution to an answer. Though, it doesn't minimize the code that much.

This can be achieved without @container requests. You say you know the dimensions... That way you can give them to the <canvas> element and it will be sized according to self aspect ratio.
Here is an example based on your code:


html {
  height:100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  background-color: #444;
  flex: none;
  height: 50px;
}

.middle {
  background-color: #222;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.items {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 20px;
  flex: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.items-cell {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.item canvas{
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, orange, purple);
}
<div class="layout">
  <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="items">
        <div class="items-cell">
        <div class="item" style="aspect-ratio: 200/300;">
          <canvas width="200" height="300"></canvas>
          <div class="block"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="items-cell">
        <div class="item" style="aspect-ratio: 1080/1920;">
          <canvas width="1080" height="1920"></canvas>
          <div class="block"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="items-cell">
        <div class="item" style="aspect-ratio: 1920/1080;">
          <canvas width="1920" height="1080"></canvas>
          <div class="block"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>




It's not working properly when the blocks don't fit vertically.

@RoboRobok I didn't check it in firefox, I give up. It is also necessary to set the aspect-ratio for it...

It doesn't work in any browser, not just Firefox.

Check again. I have updated the answer.

Now it's better, but buggy. In Sarafi it sometimes doesn't use all available space.

Taking hint from @hedfol to use aspect-ratio container queries, I managed to simplify the solution. I made all the scenarios (4 cases, combinations of horizontal / vertical container and horizontal / vertical block inside) use the same pattern. I also simplified the query by using aspect-ratio condition only.
Here's the pattern for 1920 x 1080 block as an example:
.block2 {
  aspect-ratio: 1920 / 1080;
  width: 1920px;
}

@container (aspect-ratio > 1920 / 1080) {
  .block2 {
    height: 1080px;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
  }
}

And here's the full, working snippet:


html,
body {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  background-color: #444;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 50px;
}

.middle {
  background-color: #222;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #666;
  container-type: size;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}

.block {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, orange, purple);
}

.block1 {
  aspect-ratio: 300 / 200;
  width: 300px;
}

@container (aspect-ratio > 300 / 200) {
  .block1 {
    height: 200px;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
  }
}

.block2 {
  aspect-ratio: 1920 / 1080;
  width: 1920px;
}

@container (aspect-ratio > 1920 / 1080) {
  .block2 {
    height: 1080px;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
  }
}

.block3 {
  aspect-ratio: 1080 / 1920;
  width: 1080px;
}

@container (aspect-ratio > 1080 / 1920) {
  .block3 {
    height: 1920px;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
  }
}
<div class="layout">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="items">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="block block1"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="block block2"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="block block3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>



Now I'm thinking whether it's possible to use CSS variables to simplify it even further.
